# Subquery returns more than 1 row when selecting data

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

How can I select enum data from one table with multiple rows, and use it as condition in view class, I've tried to use this in my model

```
public function get_absen($id_user, $bulan, $tahun)
    {
        $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%d-%m-%Y') AS tanggal, waktu AS jam_masuk, (SELECT waktu FROM attendance al WHERE al.tanggal = tanggal AND al.user_id = user_id OR al.keterangan != keterangan) AS jam_pulang");
        $this->db->where_in('user_id', $id_user);
        $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%m') = ", $bulan);
        $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%Y') = ", $tahun);
        $this->db->group_by("tanggal");
        $result = $this->db->get('attendance');
        return $result->result_array();
    }
```

But when I run the code, it show me this error

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row

This is my table structure

table structure:
[image: table structure]

Sorry for very late respond, but i've figured about the query i want but still don't know how to implement those queries in CI

this one for getting "Masuk" status

```
SELECT waktu, keterangan, DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, %d-%m-%Y) FROM attendance
-> WHERE keterangan IN (SELECT keterangan FROM clocks)
-> AND keterangan = "Masuk"
-> AND user_id = 15
```

and this one for getting "Pulang" status

```
SELECT waktu, keterangan, tanggal FROM attendance
-> WHERE keterangan IN (SELECT keterangan FROM clocks)
-> AND keterangan = "Pulang"
-> AND user_id = 15;
```

Then, I've tried to change the query to this one

```
public function get_absen($id_user, $bulan, $tahun)
{
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%d-%m-%Y') AS tanggal, (SELECT waktu FROM attendance WHERE keterangan IN (SELECT keterangan FROM clocks) AND keterangan = 'Masuk') AS jam_masuk, (SELECT waktu FROM attendance WHERE keterangan IN (SELECT keterangan FROM clocks) AND keterangan = 'Pulang') AS jam_pulang");
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id_user);
    $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%m') = ", $bulan);
    $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%Y') = ", $tahun);
    $this->db->group_by("tanggal");
    $result = $this->db->get('attendance');
    return $result->result_array();
}
```

But still, show me the same error, was it impossible to take those from one table?

Comment: Not enough detail to know your complete requirement.  But if you want to avoid the error, you could do this for now.  Change: `(SELECT waktu ...` to `(SELECT MIN(waktu) ...`.  You'll probably need to do this twice in your updated query and just once in the original query.

Comment: `WHERE IN keterangan = 'Pulang'` that doesn't look like a valid condition to me.  Please create a sql fiddle demo with a sufficient amount of sample data to differentiate good answers from bad answers.  I don't know why `enums` and `continuous-integration` are tagged here.  CodeIgniter allows you to compile queries for subqueries.

Comment: @mickmackusa, sorry i thought it was enums problem when i have to choose some data from a column that have enum data type, but it was wrong, and by CI mean CodeIgniter for implementing those queries.

Comment: Use groupby in your subquery